# To Get World Time via TimeZone

Tags: android, datetime

What am I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.Calendar;

import android.os.Bundle;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.view.Menu;

import android.view.View;

import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

import android.widget.Button;

import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

Button b;

EditText t;


@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);

    t=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    b.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.

getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

return true;
    }

    @Override

public void onClick(View arg0) {

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();

    String Name=t.getText().toString().trim();

    tz.setID(Name);
    }

}
```

Comment: Tired This as well but there is an error

public void onClick(View arg0)
 {
  
String Name=t.getText().toString().trim();
  
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
  
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone().setID(Name);
  
  
 }

Comment: Hard to definitively say. What are you trying to do? What do you expect should happen?

Comment: This is a dummy activity. I basically want to embed this code in an application where it speaks the time of the location I ask it.

Eg: If I ask it to tell me the time in New York.. It tells NY's local time.

Comment: As it's posted it looks like your code does this: you are setting an id on a `TimeZone` object based on the contents of an `EditText`. Not sure what kind of answer you expect? It's a big step to get to an application which speaks the time of the location, you'll need to be more specific with what is wrong with the above code.

Comment: I'm making a project based on voice recognition system. I have integrated most of the services in it. Now I want it to speak the time of a specified location.  There are two input methods.. via EditText & Speech. This is a demo code to check if the code works individually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it this way

```
        Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EST"));
        System.out.println("Day of week: " + calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)); //2 is monday
        System.out.println("Day of the month: " + calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        System.out.println("Month: " + calender.get(Calendar.MONTH)); //0 is january 3 is april
        System.out.println("Year: " + calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        System.out.println("Hour: " + calender.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        System.out.println("Minutes: " + calender.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
```

In the getTimeZone that is where you set it GMT,EST, etc.